# Is there a detailed diagram/flowchart of how browsers parse/interpret/render a web page

Tags: javascript

I was looking for a nice diagram or flowchart of the browser process after receiving the first server response with the page data of what order it interprets html, css, and javascript, and media resources (images) and renders them.

Closest thing I found was the flowchart Douglas Crockford uses to explain how the DOM gets populated, but I was looking for a little more detail into the load order than that.

Comment: You'll never know how Internet Explorer does it, it's closed source. Firefox and Chrome are open source, so you could potentially look at their code. The order won't be the same.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: Actually when I just googled for [flowchart of how browsers parse render](http://www.google.com/search?q=flowchart+of+how+browsers+parse+render) the second hit was for [Internet Explorer Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741312(v=vs.85).aspx) ;) Also I wouldn't really recommend reading millions of lines of code as a substitute for a flowchart but YMMV.

Comment: But that IE architecture page says nothing about how the browser renders a page...

Comment: @Dan Grossman: Good point. I actually thought that what I've found was [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx) that I once read - posted below by Eli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I just googled for [flowchart of how browsers parse render](http://www.google.com/search?q=flowchart+of+how+browsers+parse+render) and [how browsers work](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+browsers+work) I've found quite a few interesting articles, some of them including diagrams and flowcharts.

Comment: damn, i should have gone simpler in my google keywords.
http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about the other browsers, but I remember this flowchart floating around on Twitter for a while about the rendering from IE8 and earlier. Hope it helps partially.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx

Comment: very useful addition. i am going to be using this to do a deep dive talk about how browsers handle web applications. thanks